# C# How to avoid code duplication when the difference is in the middle of the loop

Tags: c#

Currently I have two functions like this

```
GenerateDocumentA(DocumentA docA)
{
    OpenDocumentCode();
    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i ++)
    {
        // some common per page code, var page = xxx
        SpecificCodeA(docA, page, i);
    }
    CloseDocumentCode();
}

GenerateDocumentB(DocumentB docB)
{
    OpenDocumentCode();
    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i ++)
    {
        // some common per page code, var page = xxx
        SpecificCodeB(docB, page, i);
    }
    CloseDocumentCode();
}
```

I tried to de-duplicate the code and saw this answer

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18379/how-to-remove-code-duplication-that-difference-only-a-few-lines

And faced an issue that I do not know how to pass variable from both places to `SpecificCode()`

```
GenerateDocument(Action SpecificCode)
{
    OpenDocumentCode();
    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i ++)
    {
        // some common per page code, var page = xxx
        SpecificCode(); // How to pass the current page / page index
    }
    CloseDocumentCode();
}

GenerateDocumentA(DocumentA docA)
{
    GenerateDocument( () => { } ) // how to also pass the DocumentA docA
}
```

My question is: How can i define and pass `SpecificCode()` to `GenerateDocument()` common code, knowing that `SpecificCode()` take variable in both `GenerateDocumentA()` and `GenerateDocument()` as parameter

Comment: You could use `SpecificCode.Invoke(docA, page, i)`. However you'd lose any compiler-support, as `Action` is completely unconstrained.

Comment: Thanks @MakePeaceGreatAgain 
I am not sure to understand where should I do that since inside GenerateDocument() there is no knowledge of docA. And inside GenerateDocumentA() there is no knowledge of the current loop.

I am open to switch to Func or anything else for compiler support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GenerateDocument(Action<int,int> todo)
{
    OpenDocumentCode();
    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i ++)
    {
        // some common per page code, var page = xxx
        todo(page,i);
    }
    CloseDocumentCode();
}
```

use case :

```
DocumentA docA;
GenerateDocument((int page, int i)=>
{
    SpecificCodeA(docA, page, i);
});

DocumentB docB;
GenerateDocument((int page, int i)=>
{
    SpecificCodeB(docB, page, i);
});
```

Comment: @BartHofland I edited it sorry my bad

Comment: This looks really nice!  Thank you, I will test it out. Additionally may I know the name of this kind of pattern? is it delegate / callback?

Comment: this is delegate , and `Action` is a quickly use `Generic` type delegate. and if you need return some , you can use `Func`